# How can I get fast measuring of jitter and shimmer?

Tags: phonology, phonetics

I want to be able to see fast computations of jitter and shimmer. Best would be on the fly but an online/software quick tool would be also good.

Answer (score 3):

The best way is with Praat. There are many ways to get these values within Praat. The easiest is using the Sound editor, click "show pulses", select the part that you are interested in, and look at the voice report – there are 5 varieties of jitter and 6 varieties of jitter, plus parameters that you can set (pitch and pulse setting). Ease comes at a cost, that the number is not necessarily replicable if you look a second time (moving the window left or right or zooming in and out affects pulse location therefore jitter). You also have to select at least 4 pulses to get a value. There are also script-driven methods that are immune to this window effect.